# How to use enum in Django with special characters

Tags: python, django, enums

I am using enum34 package like described [here](http://blog.richard.do/index.php/2014/02/how-to-use-enums-for-django-field-choices/).

Here is the example used in article:

```
from common.utils import ChoiceEnum

class StudentTypes(ChoiceEnum):
    freshman = 0
    sophomore = 1
    junior = 2
    senior = 3

# within your models.Model class...
student_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=StudentTypes.choices())
```

However, in my enum field I would like to have use `:` (such as `16:9`).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Alongside the example from the article, can you also include what you are trying to do? It will probably give you an interpreter error, which will help in cross-referencing with other entries on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that I do not need `enum34` package and easily do it by hand:

```
WIDE= 0
BOX = 1
RATIO_CHOICES = (
    (WIDE, '16:9'),
    (BOX, '4:3'),
)
aspect_ratio = models.IntegerField(choices=RATIO_CHOICES, default=WIDE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be sure that you understand what an enum is? In the example case, freshman is represented by `0`, sophomore by `1`, etc. You cannot use a string, such as `"16:9"` to be the representation in the enum.

The names in an enumeration need to be valid Python identifiers. However, there are other means of mapping strings, such as strings with colons, to integers or vice-versa.

Comment: 16:9 => 0 4:3 => 1, etc.

Comment: Could `16:9` and `4:3` be strings?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I have fully understood your question. Would you like to use 16:9 as an attribute in an enum? You can't because : is not a proper character for any attribute. You can't use a variable called 16:9 in your code anywhere. See: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier